# Apache Spark Java Set Memory Size

Tags: java, apache-spark, intellij-idea, apache-spark-sql

I have been searching a solution online for quite a while, but to no avail. I am trying to run a Spark Job in the client node (built and run via Intellj). For some reason, I cannot set the directory memory in the Spark session (Seems that in the client mode, the memory is allocated before JVM starts). My VM has 20G of RAM but the Spark job was killed when memory reaches 5G, roughly the default allocated driver memory size. There are some solutions suggesting running the job through spark-submit. But for Java version comparability reasons, I can't do it. There are also suggestions on trying modifying the config file under spark\conf\spark-defaults.conf, but it did not work for me either. Did anyone have the same situation and was able to resolve it? I am interested in running Java Spark in intellj and properly setting the driver memory. Your help is appreciated!

The error trace is as below

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.base/java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.<init>(HeapByteBuffer.java:61)
    at java.base/java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(ByteBuffer.java:348)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.ColumnBuilder$.ensureFreeSpace(ColumnBuilder.scala:157)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.BasicColumnBuilder.appendFrom(ColumnBuilder.scala:71)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.NativeColumnBuilder.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$columnar$NullableColumnBuilder$$super$appendFrom(ColumnBuilder.scala:97)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.NullableColumnBuilder$class.appendFrom(NullableColumnBuilder.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.NativeColumnBuilder.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$columnar$compression$CompressibleColumnBuilder$$super$appendFrom(ColumnBuilder.scala:97)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.compression.CompressibleColumnBuilder$class.appendFrom(CompressibleColumnBuilder.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.NativeColumnBuilder.appendFrom(ColumnBuilder.scala:97)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.InMemoryRelation$$anonfun$1$$anon$1.next(InMemoryRelation.scala:122)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.InMemoryRelation$$anonfun$1$$anon$1.next(InMemoryRelation.scala:97)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.memory.MemoryStore.putIteratorAsValues(MemoryStore.scala:216)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:957)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:948)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPut(BlockManager.scala:888)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPutIterator(BlockManager.scala:948)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getOrElseUpdate(BlockManager.scala:694)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.getOrCompute(RDD.scala:334)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:285)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
20/05/09 05:49:04 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.base/java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.<init>(HeapByteBuffer.java:61)
    at java.base/java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(ByteBuffer.java:348)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.ColumnBuilder$.ensureFreeSpace(ColumnBuilder.scala:157)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.BasicColumnBuilder.appendFrom(ColumnBuilder.scala:71)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.NativeColumnBuilder.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$columnar$NullableColumnBuilder$$super$appendFrom(ColumnBuilder.scala:97)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.NullableColumnBuilder$class.appendFrom(NullableColumnBuilder.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.NativeColumnBuilder.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$columnar$compression$CompressibleColumnBuilder$$super$appendFrom(ColumnBuilder.scala:97)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.compression.CompressibleColumnBuilder$class.appendFrom(CompressibleColumnBuilder.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.NativeColumnBuilder.appendFrom(ColumnBuilder.scala:97)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.InMemoryRelation$$anonfun$1$$anon$1.next(InMemoryRelation.scala:122)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.InMemoryRelation$$anonfun$1$$anon$1.next(InMemoryRelation.scala:97)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.memory.MemoryStore.putIteratorAsValues(MemoryStore.scala:216)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:957)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:948)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPut(BlockManager.scala:888)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPutIterator(BlockManager.scala:948)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getOrElseUpdate(BlockManager.scala:694)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.getOrCompute(RDD.scala:334)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:285)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)

20/05/09 05:49:04 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.base/java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.<init>(HeapByteBuffer.java:61)
    at java.base/java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(ByteBuffer.java:348)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.ColumnBuilder$.ensureFreeSpace(ColumnBuilder.scala:157)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.BasicColumnBuilder.appendFrom(ColumnBuilder.scala:71)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.NativeColumnBuilder.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$columnar$NullableColumnBuilder$$super$appendFrom(ColumnBuilder.scala:97)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.NullableColumnBuilder$class.appendFrom(NullableColumnBuilder.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.NativeColumnBuilder.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$columnar$compression$CompressibleColumnBuilder$$super$appendFrom(ColumnBuilder.scala:97)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.compression.CompressibleColumnBuilder$class.appendFrom(CompressibleColumnBuilder.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.NativeColumnBuilder.appendFrom(ColumnBuilder.scala:97)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.InMemoryRelation$$anonfun$1$$anon$1.next(InMemoryRelation.scala:122)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.InMemoryRelation$$anonfun$1$$anon$1.next(InMemoryRelation.scala:97)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.memory.MemoryStore.putIteratorAsValues(MemoryStore.scala:216)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:957)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:948)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPut(BlockManager.scala:888)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPutIterator(BlockManager.scala:948)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getOrElseUpdate(BlockManager.scala:694)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.getOrCompute(RDD.scala:334)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:285)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1435)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1423)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1422)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1422)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1650)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1605)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1594)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:628)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1918)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1931)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1944)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1958)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.count(RDD.scala:1157)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$class.count(JavaRDDLike.scala:455)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.AbstractJavaRDDLike.count(JavaRDDLike.scala:45)
    at edu.upenn.cis455.pagerank.SparkAppMain.main(SparkAppMain.java:149)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.base/java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.<init>(HeapByteBuffer.java:61)
    at java.base/java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(ByteBuffer.java:348)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.ColumnBuilder$.ensureFreeSpace(ColumnBuilder.scala:157)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.BasicColumnBuilder.appendFrom(ColumnBuilder.scala:71)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.NativeColumnBuilder.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$columnar$NullableColumnBuilder$$super$appendFrom(ColumnBuilder.scala:97)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.NullableColumnBuilder$class.appendFrom(NullableColumnBuilder.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.NativeColumnBuilder.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$columnar$compression$CompressibleColumnBuilder$$super$appendFrom(ColumnBuilder.scala:97)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.compression.CompressibleColumnBuilder$class.appendFrom(CompressibleColumnBuilder.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.NativeColumnBuilder.appendFrom(ColumnBuilder.scala:97)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.InMemoryRelation$$anonfun$1$$anon$1.next(InMemoryRelation.scala:122)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.InMemoryRelation$$anonfun$1$$anon$1.next(InMemoryRelation.scala:97)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.memory.MemoryStore.putIteratorAsValues(MemoryStore.scala:216)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:957)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:948)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPut(BlockManager.scala:888)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPutIterator(BlockManager.scala:948)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getOrElseUpdate(BlockManager.scala:694)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.getOrCompute(RDD.scala:334)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:285)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
```

Comment: Thank you! The error trace is edited above

Comment: This is a class project, so I'd like to keep the code to myself (thanks for your understanding). The code basically reads many records from a SQL database connection, convert it to a Java RDD. The error happens when I try to compute some stats on this RDD (since Spark is lazy evaluation)/

Comment: Sure, but what I am asking is how to increase memory.

Answer (score 0):

For Intellij Idea set

```
Run\Debug Configurations ---> VM options : -Xmx1g
```

From your code you can try setting the memory as

```
sparkConf.set("spark.testing.memory", "1073741824")
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried that, but it did not work. The application was killed when memory usage is over 5GB regardless. This the default driver memory  size, which I cannot somewhat override.

Comment: Are you using JDK8 or JDK8+ and have you set the memory > 5g ?

Comment: Yes I am using JDK > 8. I am not sure how to set JDK memory?